# What is an intuitive or simple proof of Gleason's theorem and how it relates to the Born rule?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, probability, density-operator, born-rule

What is an intuitive or simple proof of [Gleason's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gleason%27s_theorem) and how it relates to the Born rule? I tried to read the articles, but the proof seemed big and the kind that are unintuitive (im not Accustomed with math rigour so its even more difficult for me) , perhaps following some pre determined step sequence, i don't know, so I was wondering if there is any intuitive or simple proof enough for it to be written in the answers here.

Other thing that i add after i post, how born rule emerges from this, and since the theorem Applies for dimensions of the hilbert space bigger than 3 what happens for less of that in the way to derive the born rule for this states,we have to add some thing to derive the born rule for less than 3?

Comment: WIkipedia gives a pretty good outline of the proof, listing the various steps (though of course without the details of how those steps are accomplished).  Which of those steps do you want more detail for?

Comment: If possible, all steps

Comment: I'm trying to understand the born rule by this theorem, but it seems that it only applies to hilbert spaces with dimension greater than 3,so do not know how to continue to see how this relates to the born rule

Comment: The simplest known proof is the one by Cooke, Keane and Moran that is cited in the Wikipedia article.  Have you read that proof?  If so, where *exactly* did you stop following it?